# References on completion and Tor/Ext

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I am currently working on a thesis that relates to the Functors $\text{Tor}$ and $\text{Ext}$. I have found some work on localization with respect to them when it comes to information in my books but I am struggling to find anything when it comes to the completion of rings or modules. With completion I mean that for a ring $R$ with norm $||\cdot ||$ we have that $R^\ast$ is the completion where all elements are the equivalence classes of cauchy sequences of $R$ with respect to our norm.

Are there any good articles or books on this that could be recommended? The question is about the general relationship between the functors and the completion when it occures.

Answer (score 1):

A special case of completion is when $R$ is a commutative ring, $I$ is an ideal in $R$, and we complete $R$ with respect to $I$; this is the $I$-adic completion of $R$.  It is a theorem (a consequence of Artin--Rees) that if $R$ is Noetherian, then any $I$-adic completion of $R$ is flat over $R$.

In this case you can use results on Tor and flat base-change to get something.